# Flash AS3 Random function, 0-9, EXCEPT 3 for example

Tags: actionscript-3, math, random

I wonder how to make a Math.random() function, or something similar where it chooses a number from 0-9. But as the program progresses, another random variable will appear. That random value is what I want removed from the 0-9 scale. (The other random variable is also from 0-9)

Comment: Can you share examples of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.random( ) returns a number from 0-1

```
function randomNum( modifier:int ):Number{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(9-modifier));
}
```

New edited code
Pass the array you want to grab an element out of and it will return the value of the randomed element.
use seedArray.splice(0, 1); to remove elements from the array in this case it would be the first element.

```
var seedArray:Array = [10,1000,20,245,874687,57,3456];
trace(this.randomElement(seedArray) )
seedArray.splice(0, 1);
trace(this.randomElement(seedArray) )
seedArray.splice(0, 1);
trace(this.randomElement(seedArray) )
seedArray.splice(0, 1);
trace(this.randomElement(seedArray) )
seedArray.splice(0, 1);
trace(this.randomElement(seedArray) )
seedArray.splice(0, 1);
trace(this.randomElement(seedArray) )
seedArray.splice(0, 1);
trace(this.randomElement(seedArray) )

    function randomElement( arr:Array ):Number{
      var rand:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
      return arr[rand];
    }
```

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random()*10)` then

Comment: as 1*10=10 that is not what he asked for

Comment: That don't work. i have tried it. The thing is... When I use the:

function randomNum( modifier:int ):Number{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(9-modifier));
}

I get for example a number between 0-4. But I need that random function to pick a number out of an array. I am going to remove 1 of the indexes of the array each time I push a button. So If I use that function, I suddenly have locked out 5 indexes instead of the one I had as modifier. 
Short: I need a random function that still works to choose an array, when I remove an index.

Comment: well you didn't say anything about picking from an array. give me 5 minutes i will update

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
private function zeroToNineExcept(toExclude:int):int{
    var retVal: int = -1;
    if(toExclude < 0 || toExclude > 9) {
        //trace a message, throw an argument error, ...
        return retVal;
    }
    while(retVal = Math.round(Math.random() * 9)){
        if(retVal == toExclude){ 
            continue;
        }else{ 
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NOt sure. this is how mine looks like:
Array's being created 0-9.

var rand:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
question.text = theArray[rand]

What I want to do in between each time I push the button, is splice one of the indexes of the array, and the still make the "rand" work for printing the text on question. (My array's keep texts)

Comment: @Kasper - so you need to return 9 items in random order and each one can be returned only once&

Answer (score 0):

This function will get a random array element. Then splice that element out of the array and return the value of the element. The return value and result data types are the only thing that should have to be changed.

```
private function getRandomArrayElement(arr:Array):string
{
    var index:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    var result:string = arr[index];
    arr.splice(index, 1);

    return result;
}
```

If your wanting to maintain the data in the array and return a randomized array This will work.

```
private function randomizeArray(arr:Array):Array
{
    var result:Array = [];

    while (arr.length > 0)
    {
        result.push(arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1));
    }

    return result;
}
```

My test data was as follows.

```
var testArray:Array = ["Hi", "Bye", "Okay", "Yes", "No", "Maybe", "Sometimes", "Anywhere", "You said it!"];
```

Comment: So this does so I can't get the same question from the array twice?

Comment: For the second one you would use an extra array. someArray = randomizeArray(theArrayWithMyStrings) then you can do all your stuff on someArray because it is now random. Your original array is NOT messed up and the data is preserved in its original form so you can have it for later. (when your ready to randomize it again and start the process all over). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you do not have to keep the original data safe you can just do myArray = randomize(myArray) and it will just mix up the array for you....... Oh no it won't give you the same question twice. Once you randomize the array you can just got through them. myArray[0] [1] etc etc. and they will be in random order.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to do the randomization up front:

```
var randomValues:Array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
randomValues.sort(function(a:int, b:int):int {return Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1});
```

After this initialization, `randomValues.pop()` will get you an unused value from the array.